# Efficient Way to create a 2d array of random shuffling of a range of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

I need to create a N x M numpy array of randomly shuffled numbers 0 to N. That is to say that each row of the matrix has exactly one of each numbers 0 to N in a random order with no repeating elements and every number is represented.

The best I've been able to come up with so far is (for N = 10 and M = 5)

```
import random
import numpy as np

a = np.array([random.sample(range(10), 10) for x in range(5)])
```

which gives me

```
[[5 9 1 3 8 2 6 4 0 7]
 [4 8 5 2 9 3 7 6 0 1]
 [8 4 6 7 9 2 0 5 1 3]
 [3 5 4 9 2 0 6 7 1 8]
 [6 0 4 7 3 2 1 8 5 9]]
```

My current solution does work, but I'd like to only have one random library if possible (I'm using numpy elsewhere so a numpy only solution would be ideal). I'm assuming numpy has an easier way to do this, but I'm currently missing it.

Comment: import numpy as np, of course.... then ... np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5, 10))

Comment: @JohnColeman that was my initial thought, but I wasn't sure how to create the array so that it has the same random 0->N but in different orders

Comment: @NaN, the problem is i need it to be the range(0, N) but shuffled. I.E. no repeated elements and every element is there exactly once.

Comment: Edit your question to reflect this

Comment: @NaN I've tried to make the question more clear

Comment: My current solution does work, but i'd like to only use one random library if possible (preferably numpy)

Comment: It doesn't reduce the number of library calls you need to make, but `a = np.array([np.random.permutation(10) for _ in range(5)])` might be cleaner.

Comment: Thanks @Divakar, that was a perfect answer. Guess i didn't find the correct search terms when i was digging around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the issue is simply to only use one random library (as you said in your comments), you could just use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with the argument `replace=False`, which ensures each element is not repeated:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.stack([np.random.choice(range(10), 10, replace=False) for _ in range(5)])

>>> a
array([[0, 9, 3, 5, 8, 7, 1, 4, 6, 2],
       [5, 6, 8, 3, 0, 4, 7, 9, 2, 1],
       [7, 4, 9, 5, 0, 1, 6, 8, 3, 2],
       [9, 0, 3, 8, 5, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2],
       [5, 6, 0, 1, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 2]])
```